# Better Enumerable.Range for both ascending and descending ranges?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Suppose I have two points, `int x1, x2`, where `x1` can be larger, smaller or equal to `x2`. I want to generate all integer numbers between those two points inclusive (starting with `x1` and ending with `x2`), or just value of `x1` if both two points are equal. Is there any elegant way to generate `IEnumerable<int>` with those values?

Comment: nothing built in. aggregate could do it but it'd be overkill. make your own, it shouldn't be more than 5 lines.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this iterator block:

```
IEnumerable<int> CreateRange(int x1, int x2) {
  var increment = x2 > x1 ? 1 : -1;
  for (var i = x1; i != x2; i += increment)
    yield return i;
  yield return x2;
}
```

It's efficient and creating a range is just as clean as using `Enumerable.Range`:

```
CreateRange(10, 5).Select( ... )
```

Comment: I want to keep the order

Comment: What order? @user2341923

Comment: starting with `x1` and ending with `x2`, even if `x1 > x2`

Comment: This behaves differently than `Enumerable.Range` which takes a starting number and a count and generates the sequence. This seems to take a starting number and an ending number (and count in this case would be x2-x1).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stick with single LINQ statement -

```
Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Abs(x2 - x1) + 1).Select(i => x1 + i * Math.Sign(x2 - x1))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
//normal order works
int x1 = 5;
int x2 = 10;
int len = Math.Abs(x2 - x1) + 1;

var range = x1 < x2 ? Enumerable.Range(x1, len) : Enumerable.Range(x2, len).Reverse();

 //reverse order works (the same code for range)
 x1 = 10;
 x2 = 5;
 len = Math.Abs(x2 - x1) + 1;

 range = x1 < x2 ? Enumerable.Range(x1, len) : Enumerable.Range(x2, len).Reverse();
```

Comment: The problem with Reverse is that it needs to know the last element before being able to yield. In the actual .NET Framework implementation, it means creating a buffer of the values before yielding, delaying the first item and using memory. If the collection is small and in memory, it's probably not that bad but a streaming or large object creating collection could mean trouble.